# How to access a child of a widget in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm a newbie using Kivy. I defined a FloatLayout object with a Button child. Is there anyway to access the Button on_press event and background images?

Here is the code I tried:

```
<Tecla2@FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        size_hint: (0.95,1.05)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        text: ""

Tecla2:
    self.Button.background_normal: "images/tecla_normal1.png"
    self.Button.background_down: "images/tecla_down1.png"
    self.Button.on_press: if(len(texto.text)<text_len): texto.text+="1"
```

An alternate solution (the one I currently implemented) is defining a Button and using a new FloatLayout for every instance, but it lacks elegance:

```
<Tecla@Button>:
    size_hint: (0.95,1.05)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    text: ""

FloatLayout:                    
    Tecla:
        background_normal: "images/tecla_normal2.png"
        background_down: "images/tecla_down2.png"
        on_press: if(len(texto.text)<text_len): texto.text+="2"
```

Is there anyway to do this using kivy language? This is the simplest example, but I've already needed to do the same in other situations.

Comment: What is it you want to make?
A FloatLayout with many Buttons or many FloatLayouts with one button each?

Comment: It's a grid with many FloatLayouts with one button each.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to access the Button on_press event and background images?

Well, you can use the relevant properties of the button you create:

```
<Tecla2@FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        size_hint: (0.95,1.05)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        text: ""
        background_normal: "images/tecla_normal1.png"
        background_down: "images/tecla_down1.png"
        on_press: if(len(texto.text)<text_len): texto.text+="1"
```

Maybe there is something else you're looking for?

Comment: I can be done, but every instance has different backgrounds and different codes for the on_press event. Both still need to be edited after the instantiation.